# Parse file and extract lines between blocks with python

Tags: python

I have a file that I need to parse and extract some specific lines from. This is an example of the file data:

```
dn: uid=portaladmin,ou=people,ou=myrealm,dc=portalDomain
objectclass: wlsUser objectclass: top 
objectclass: person 
objectclass: organizationalPerson 
objectclass: inetOrgPerson 
cn: portaladmin 
sn: portaladmin 
description: Admin for portal domain 
uid: portaladmin userpassword:: e3NzaGF9L3JYUldtVERBUklCdWM3NGtBSlJQVFVjQ04yRmNkU3o= 
wlsMemberOf: cn=PortalSystemAdministrators,ou=groups,ou=myrealm,dc=portalDom  ain

dn: uid=weblogic,ou=people,ou=myrealm,dc=portalDomain 
objectclass: wlsUser 
objectclass: top 
objectclass: person 
objectclass: organizationalPerson 
objectclass: inetOrgPerson 
cn: weblogic 
sn: weblogic 
description: This user is the default administrator. 
uid: weblogic 
userpassword:: e3NzaGF9VHhObDZhTlBpZTFSa2VVeTRTak1vWm0yTFJmdlN4RE8= 
wlsMemberOf: cn=Administrators,ou=groups,ou=myrealm,dc=portalDomain 
wlsMemberOf: cn=PortalSystemAdministrators,ou=groups,ou=myrealm,dc=portalDomain
```

As you can see the information is in blocks and I need to extract lines with (`cn:`, `sn:`, `description:`, `uid:` and `userpassword:`) values, also need to tell the script to search for specifics `uid` or `cn` from a list.

I'm not a experienced programmer and that's why I came here to ask the gurus on this. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I only got as far as reading the file and print lines. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the lines using str.startswith,passing a tuple of the substrings:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(("cn:","sn:", "description:", "uid:","userpassword:")):
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
cn: portaladmin
sn: portaladmin
description: Admin for portal domain
uid: portaladmin userpassword:: e3NzaGF9L3JYUldtVERBUklCdWM3NGtBSlJQVFVjQ04yRmNkU3o=
cn: weblogic
sn: weblogic
description: This user is the default administrator.
uid: weblogic
userpassword:: e3NzaGF9VHhObDZhTlBpZTFSa2VVeTRTak1vWm0yTFJmdlN4RE8=
```

Based on your comment if you want to search for substrings you can use `any`:

```
  if any(sub in line for sub in ("cn: somestring", "sn: somestring", "description: somestring", "uid: somestring", "userpassword: somestring")):
```

If the pattern is more complicated then you will probably need a regex but without knowing exactly what you want to extract then it is not possible to suggest a viable regex

Comment: Thank you Padraic, it did works! Now, how can I tell the script to do the same but telling it to search for certain string and print lines from those strings?

Comment: What are you actually trying to extract from your example, I think a regex would be suitable but I need to know what it is you are trying to extract

Comment: Well, since the file is almost 18mbs big and a lot of lines, I want the script to search for certain values in the lines for example (search for cn: somestring or uid: somestring) and print the values of cn:, sn:, description:, uid: and userpasswords from it. I don't know If I make it clear to understand.

Comment: You mean `if "cn: somestring"` in line?

Comment: no, is like giving the script a list like (names) and based on that list, search the whole file and if it finds that name then print out those records.

Comment: You need to add an example to your question as it is pretty unclear how a list of names fits into what you originally asked

Comment: Sorry Padraic, like I said, not to bright programming so don't know how to explain my self. I got the idea, but not how to express it. Your example gave me a start, now I need to modify to create a list of users and make the script to search for those users and print those 5 lines where the cn: "someuser" or uid: "someuser" appears.

Answer (score -1):

```
extractedLines = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for item in ["cn:", "sn:", "description:", "uid:", "userpassword:"]:
            if item in line:
                extractedLines.append(line)
```